# Can't Get the a value from HTML code using html-agility-pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I want to get a value from HTML code and I am using this C# code to get the value from this HTML code using *HtmlAgilityPack*.

I only want the address and telephone number

```
<div class="company-info">
    <div id="o-company" class="edit-overlay-section" style="padding-top:5px; width: 400px;">
        <a href="http://www.manta.com/c/mm23df2/us-cellular" class="company-name">
            <h1 class="profile-company_name" itemprop="name">US Cellular</h1>
        </a>
    </div>      
    <div class="addr addr-co-header-gamma" itemprop="address"itemscope=""itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <em>United States Cellular Corporation</em>
        <div class="company-address">   
        <div itemprop="streetAddress">2401 12th Avenue NW # 104B</div>
            <span class="addressLocality" itemprop="addressLocality">Ardmore</span>,
            <span class="addressRegion" itemprop="addressRegion">OK</span>      
            <span class="addresspostalCode" itemprop="postalCode">73401-1471</span>
        </div>
        <dl class="phone_info"><dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="tel" itemprop="telephone">(580) 490-3333</dd>
...
```

C# Code:

```
private HtmlDocument ParseLink(string URL)
{ 
    HtmlDocument hDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    try
    {
        WebClient wClient = new WebClient();

        byte[] bData = wClient.DownloadData(pageurl);

        hDoc.LoadHtml(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bData));
        Response.Write("<table><tr><td>");

        foreach (HtmlNode hNode in hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@itemprop='company-address']"))
        {
            Response.Write(hNode.InnerText.ToString());
        }
        Response.Write("</tr></td><td>");

        foreach (HtmlNode hNode in hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@itemprop='addressLocality']"))
        {

            Response.Write(hNode.InnerText.ToString());
        }
        Response.Write("</tr></td><td>");   

        foreach (HtmlNode hNode in hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@itemprop='addressRegion']"))
        {
            Response.Write(hNode.InnerText.ToString());
        }

        Response.Write("</tr></td><td>");

        foreach (HtmlNode hNode in hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@itemprop='postalCode']"))
        {
            Response.Write(hNode.InnerText.ToString());
        }

        Response.Write("</tr></td><td>"); 

        foreach (HtmlNode hNode in hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dd[@itemprop='telephone']"))
        {
            Response.Write(hNode.InnerText.ToString());
        }
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write("</tr></table>");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        hDoc.LoadHtml("");
    }

    return hDoc;
}
```

But when ever compile this code i get this error:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

Is there anyone who can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: i tried but cant get any solution thats why post here

Comment: Maybe this helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287892/htmlagilitypack-reference-not-found-only-after-building-my-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTML Agility pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information about the exception you are getting (like in which line the exception is thrown), but...

The `SelectNodes` method will return `null` if no items matching the *XPath* expression were found, which means you will have to check if the returned value is `null` before iterating over the nodes. Something like:

```
var companyAddressNodes = hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@itemprop='company-address']");

if (companyAddressNodes == null) {
    //Throw properly exception here, log the error, or do anything you want...
    throw new Exception("No company address node found. Perhaps the page layout changed?");
}

foreach (HtmlNode hNode in )
{
    Response.Write(hNode.InnerText.ToString());
}
```